# Strongly typed resource in RequiredAttribute, StringLengthAttribute and so on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In normal usage, if I have ASP.NET MVC model with validation attributes but the error message should come from resources people would do

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UsernameRequired")]
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UsernameLength")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

But is there a way to have the resource name strongly typed, for example I could use `Errors.UsernameLength` or `Errors.UsernameRequired` in the attributes? In case if somebody changed the resource key name, it is much easier to be picked by compiler.

Comment: If `Errors.UsernameLength` is an internal constant field of some `Errors` class containing actual resource key string - then it should work just fine with `ErrorMessageResourceName = Errors.UsernameLength`

Comment: @Andrei `Errors.UsernameLength` is from my internal resource, not a constant.